Blender script distorts large object
I am creating coin using cylinder and adding text on it. I am using blender script and calling script via command line. Sizes of coins ar 45mm, 60mm,, 75mm, 90mm and 105mm. It is working fine for small coin 45mm. For bigger coin size 75mm, 90mm etc. sometimes text gets distorted or some part of the letters gets corrupted.
I am using window server with 4GB RAM where I am calling this script. I have noticed CPU utilization is going 100% when we are creating coin using blender python script. Is server configuration creating this issue? Please let me know how to fix this issue.
Below is script. It works fine for scale 22.5. For scales 45, 50 most of times works fine but sometimes text gets distorted.
import bpy
import bmesh
import math

SUBDIVISION = 70
HEIGHT = 0.1
RADIUS = 1
RIM = 0.3
DEPTH = 0
SCALE = 22.5

RIM_TEXT_SIZE = [0.23, 0.23]
CENTER_TEXT_SIZE = [0.23, 0.23]
CENTER_TEXT_OFFSET = [0, 0, 0]
RIM_TEXT_OFFSET = [0, 0, 0]
TEXT_FONT = [None, None]
TEXT_EXTRUDE = 0.04 
TEXT_CONTENT = ["top head", "bottom head", "center head", "top tail", "bottom tail", "center tail"]

GRAPHIC = None
GRAPHIC_SCALE = 0.05
GRAPHIC_EXTRUDE = 0.05
GRAPHIC_OFFSET = [0,0,0]
GRAPHIC_RESOLUTION = 7

STL_EXPORT = None
STL_NAME = "coin.stl"

# example function call:            
# GenerateCoin(coin_stl_export = "C:\\Users\\hp\\Desktop", coin_graphic = "C:\\Users\\hp\\Downloads\\logo.png", coin_text_font = ["C:\\WINDOWS\\Fonts\\ROCC____.TTF", "C:\\WINDOWS\\Fonts\\ROCC____.TTF"], coin_text_content = ["test", "head", "", "top tail", "bottom tail", "center tail"], coin_graphic_offset = [-0.03,0,0], coin_graphic_scale = 0.3)

def GenerateCoin(coin_subdivision = SUBDIVISION, coin_height = HEIGHT, coin_radius = RADIUS, coin_rim = RIM,\
    coin_depth = DEPTH, coin_scale = SCALE, coin_rim_text_size = RIM_TEXT_SIZE, coin_center_text_size = CENTER_TEXT_SIZE,\
    coin_text_extrude = TEXT_EXTRUDE, coin_text_content =  TEXT_CONTENT, coin_center_text_offset = CENTER_TEXT_OFFSET,\
    coin_rim_text_offset = RIM_TEXT_OFFSET, coin_text_font = TEXT_FONT, coin_graphic = GRAPHIC,\
    coin_graphic_offset = GRAPHIC_OFFSET, coin_graphic_scale = GRAPHIC_SCALE, coin_graphic_extrude = GRAPHIC_EXTRUDE,\
    coin_graphic_resolution = GRAPHIC_RESOLUTION, coin_stl_export = STL_EXPORT, coin_stl_name = STL_NAME):
     
    # clear the scene & set context
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
    bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False)
    bpy.context.scene.unit_settings.scale_length = 0.01
    bpy.context.scene.unit_settings.scale_length = 0.01

    # create coin mesh from cylinder
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(depth = coin_height, radius = coin_radius, vertices = coin_subdivision, enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))

    coin = bpy.context.active_object
    coinMesh = coin.data

    # using bmesh
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
    bmCoin = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(coinMesh)

    # select top and botom faces
    for face in bmCoin.faces: 
        face.select = False
    bmCoin.faces.ensure_lookup_table()    
    BottomFace = bmCoin.faces[SUBDIVISION + 1]
    TopFace = bmCoin.faces[SUBDIVISION - 2]

    # inset the faces
    bmesh.ops.inset_region(bmCoin, faces = [BottomFace, TopFace], thickness=coin_rim, depth=0)
    bmesh.ops.inset_region(bmCoin, faces = [BottomFace], thickness=0, depth=-coin_depth)
    
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
    
    # manipulate text
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
    TextManipulate(coin, coin_rim_text_size, coin_center_text_size, coin_text_extrude,\
    coin_height, coin_depth, coin_text_content, coin_radius, coin_rim, coin_center_text_offset,\
    coin_rim_text_offset, coin_text_font)
    
    # final geometry clean up
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type="EDGE")
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_non_manifold()
    bpy.ops.mesh.edge_split()
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type="VERT")    
    bpy.ops.object.vertex_group_select()
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='INVERT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.remove_doubles(threshold=1e-05)
    
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type="EDGE")
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_non_manifold()
    bpy.ops.mesh.delete(type='EDGE')
    
    # export to stl
    if coin_stl_export != None:
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = coin
        
        bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(coin_scale, coin_scale, coin_scale))
        
        stl_path = coin_stl_export + '\\' + coin_stl_name
        bpy.ops.export_mesh.stl(filepath= stl_path)
    
def TextManipulate(coin, coin_rim_text_size, coin_center_text_size, coin_text_extrude,\
    coin_height, coin_depth, coin_text_content, coin_radius, coin_rim, coin_center_text_offset,\
    coin_rim_text_offset, coin_text_font):
    
    ''' perform text manipulations and placement on the coin'''
    
    # create a collection to store all text objects
    text_head_coll = bpy.data.collections.new("TextHeadCollection")
    bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(text_head_coll)
    
    text_tail_coll = bpy.data.collections.new("TextTailCollection")
    bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(text_tail_coll)
    
    for text_index in range(6):
                
        # create text object
        bpy.ops.object.text_add(enter_editmode=True, align='WORLD', location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
        text = bpy.context.active_object
       
        # apply text settings
        if text_index in (0, 1, 2):
            face = 0
        else:
            face = 1
        
        if text_index in (2,5):
            text.data.size = coin_center_text_size[face]
        else:
            text.data.size = coin_rim_text_size[face]
            
        if coin_text_font:
            text_font = bpy.data.fonts.load(coin_text_font[face])
            text.data.font = text_font

    
        
        # clear the default text and write the text content
        bpy.ops.font.delete(type='PREVIOUS_WORD')
        bpy.ops.font.text_insert(text = coin_text_content[text_index])

        
        # set verticle location
        if text_index in (0, 1, 2):
            text.location[2] += (coin_height / 2 - coin_depth) - 0.01
            if text_index != 2:
                text.location[2] += coin_depth
        else:
            text.location[2] += -(coin_height / 2 - coin_depth) - 0.01
            if text_index != 5:
                text.location[2] -= coin_depth
                
                
    
        # allign the origin and orientation
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
        text.data.space_character = 1.05
        text.data.align_x = 'CENTER'
        text.data.align_y = 'CENTER'
        
        if text_index in (0, 3):
            text.location[0] = math.pi * (coin_radius - coin_rim/2)
        elif text_index in (1, 4):            
            bpy.ops.transform.mirror(orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', constraint_axis=(False, True, False))
            bpy.ops.transform.mirror(orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', constraint_axis=(True, False, False))
        
        if text_index >= 3:
            bpy.ops.transform.mirror(orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', constraint_axis=(True, False, False))
        
        if text_index in (2, 5):
            text.location[0] += coin_center_text_offset[0]
            text.location[1] += coin_center_text_offset[1]
            text.location[2] += coin_center_text_offset[2]
        else:
            text.location[0] += coin_rim_text_offset[0]
            text.location[1] += coin_rim_text_offset[1]
            text.location[2] += coin_rim_text_offset[2]    
            
        # convert to mesh
        bpy.ops.object.convert(target='MESH')
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')         
        bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
        
        bpy.ops.mesh.remove_doubles()
        
        bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_region_move(MESH_OT_extrude_region={"use_normal_flip":False, "use_dissolve_ortho_edges":False, "mirror":False}, TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":(0, 0, coin_text_extrude), "orient_type":'GLOBAL', "orient_matrix":((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), "orient_matrix_type":'GLOBAL', "constraint_axis":(False, False, True), "mirror":False, "use_proportional_edit":False, "proportional_edit_falloff":'SMOOTH', "proportional_size":1, "use_proportional_connected":False, "use_proportional_projected":False, "snap":False, "snap_target":'CLOSEST', "snap_point":(0, 0, 0), "snap_align":False, "snap_normal":(0, 0, 0), "gpencil_strokes":False, "cursor_transform":False, "texture_space":False, "remove_on_cancel":False, "release_confirm":False, "use_accurate":False, "use_automerge_and_split":False})
        bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
        bpy.ops.mesh.quads_convert_to_tris(quad_method='BEAUTY', ngon_method='BEAUTY') 
        QuickCleanGeometry(text)
        
        # flip normals
        if text_index in (3, 4, 5):
            bpy.ops.mesh.flip_normals()

        
        # create curve to wrap text around
        bpy.ops.curve.primitive_bezier_circle_add(enter_editmode=False, align='WORLD',radius = coin_radius - coin_rim/2, location=(0, 0, 0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
        curve = bpy.context.active_object
    
        # wrap text around the curve
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = text
        if text_index not in (2, 5):
            text.modifiers.new("Curve modifier", 'CURVE')
            text.modifiers["Curve modifier"].object = curve 
            bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier="Curve modifier")
        
        # delete the curve
        bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = curve
        bpy.ops.object.delete()
        
        
        # add text object to a collection
        if text_index in (0, 1, 2):
            bpy.data.collections['TextHeadCollection'].objects.link(text)
        else: 
            bpy.data.collections['TextTailCollection'].objects.link(text)    
        
    
    # apply union boolean between the head side and text objects
    coin.modifiers.new("Boolean modifier", type='BOOLEAN')
    coin.modifiers["Boolean modifier"].operation = 'UNION'
    coin.modifiers["Boolean modifier"].use_hole_tolerant = True
    coin.modifiers["Boolean modifier"].use_self = True
    coin.modifiers["Boolean modifier"].operand_type = 'COLLECTION'
    coin.modifiers["Boolean modifier"].collection = text_head_coll
    
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = coin
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier="Boolean modifier")

    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
    
    
    # apply union boolean between the tail side and text objects
    coin.modifiers.new("Boolean modifier", type='BOOLEAN')
    coin.modifiers["Boolean modifier"].operation = 'DIFFERENCE'
    coin.modifiers["Boolean modifier"].use_hole_tolerant = True
    coin.modifiers["Boolean modifier"].use_self = True
    coin.modifiers["Boolean modifier"].operand_type = 'COLLECTION'
    coin.modifiers["Boolean modifier"].collection = text_tail_coll
    
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = coin
    bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier="Boolean modifier")

    QuickCleanGeometry(coin)
    
    
    # remove the collection
    for obj in text_head_coll.objects:
        bpy.data.objects.remove(obj, do_unlink=True)
    bpy.data.collections.remove(text_head_coll)    
        
    for obj in text_tail_coll.objects:
        bpy.data.objects.remove(obj, do_unlink=True)
    bpy.data.collections.remove(text_tail_coll)

    
    
def QuickCleanGeometry(obj):
    '''Give the mesh a quick clean up'''
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
    
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
    
    bpy.ops.mesh.dissolve_limited()
    for i in range(30):
        bpy.ops.mesh.quads_convert_to_tris(quad_method='BEAUTY', ngon_method='BEAUTY')
        bpy.ops.mesh.dissolve_degenerate()
    bpy.ops.mesh.dissolve_limited()
    
    bpy.ops.mesh.quads_convert_to_tris(quad_method='BEAUTY', ngon_method='BEAUTY')    

def view3d_find( return_area = False ):
    '''returns first 3d view, normally we get from context'''
    for area in bpy.context.window.screen.areas:
        if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
            v3d = area.spaces[0]
            rv3d = v3d.region_3d
            for region in area.regions:
                if region.type == 'WINDOW':
                    if return_area: return region, rv3d, v3d, area
                    return region, rv3d, v3d
    return None, None

Thanks

Something's wrong with your script. I'm confused with this definition def TextManipulate(coin, coin_rim_text_size, coin_center_text_size, coin_text_extrude,\     bpy.data.collections.remove(text_tail_coll) why does it take 4 arguments but doesn't use any of the arguments? and then where does text_tail_coll come from in that function. And then on line 76 it is passing 12 parameters to this function even though it only accepts 4 arguments. Also please read How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

@HarryMcKenzie I have modified the code. It was missed during copy paste. The above code is working fine the issue is randomly sometimes when we are generating large object some part of text/object get distort.

@Tarlok How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example

This looks like AI generated code. Was this code generated with the help of some language module? If so you must provide attribution and disclose origin

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos This is not AI generated code. Code is written in python blender script.

After doing testing on different-2 servers I found that the issue is with CPU utilization. Text distorts when CPU utilization is going to100%. I tried with 4 CPU error frequency reduced then I tired with 8 CPU it reduced more but still sometime randomly CPU going to 100%. I am not using GPU, do GPU compulsory for blender? If I don't want GPU then how many CPU needed to run script smoothly? Please help me.
